# How to tell Siri <<EOF>> when I am done talking, eg, over steady background noise?

Tags: iphone, ios, siri

Sometimes the ambient background noise in my environment is enough to keep Siri engaged after I've just asked Siri for something. Siri can hear my voice clearly atop the background noise, as evidenced by her transcription of what she's heard so far -- the problem is, Siri keeps on listening until there is quiet.

Examples of the type of background noise I am referring to include TV shows, boisterous guests, music, lawnmower, construction, etc.

[Similar to this question regarding telling Siri about newlines](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/230356/18387), is there a way to issue some kind of military-style <<\over>> or <<\end transmission>> or unix-style <<\EOF>>to let her know that there is nothing else to hear, and to process my input as-is?

Comment: You can hold down the siri button while giving your command, when you release it she will stop listening. I know you're not asking for this but maybe it will help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you press and hold the Home button down and keep it down the whole time you are asking Siri the question, letting go of the Home button will signify "end of question." It takes a little getting used to but it works great. This is not exactly what you asked for but it solves your problem.

Comment: I'd kind of forgotten there was another way to use Siri besides this one.

Comment: Isn't that funny. For me it was just the opposite.

Comment: I've accepted this answer because this bit of trivia provided (holding down home button until done talking to Siri) has helped me to completely circumvent two problems: Siri listening too long, and Siri not listening long enough! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to give Siri an EOF-type word that you're done talking.  Similar to what @dennismuys said in the comment, you can tap the Siri waveform on the screen when you're done talking.

While this isn't the key-word you're looking for, it will serve the same purpose.